# how to give another function a value in string format

Tags: ios, swift

I created a UIbutton in my project and add target:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonDidSelect", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And I created a function

```
func buttonDidSelect(index: Int){
    println("button at \(index) pressed")
}
```

But the function need a value.
What should i do to give the function the value with string? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First, if you want to pass a value to `buttonDidSelect`, you need to write the selector name as `"buttonDidSelect:"` (notice the colon).

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonDidSelect:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Second, the value will be the *button*, not some integer. If you want an integer, give each button a `tag` and now you can get that `tag` inside your function.

```
func buttonDidSelect(button:UIButton){
    println("button at \(button.tag) pressed")
}
```